# How to properly implement a custom timer event?

Tags: events, wxwidgets

I do some experiments with wxWidgets and try to fire an event every 20ms. My first approach was to use wxTimer and at first glance it seemed to work fine but measuring times showed that although the timer is set to 20ms it fires only at a period > 30ms. I found that to be a common issue.
To have that more precise I made a class that creates a thread and in the thread function uses std::this_thread::sleep_for (20) and post a wxCommandEvent afterwards. This works fine concerning the time of 20ms. But it has other drawbacks that were not present with the wxTimer solution:

- when resizing the window the timer triggers but the posted event is not processed
- the same when opening a menu like File or About menu

Which is the right way to do that? Can I give an event a higher priority? Can I post a wxTimerEvent from my own code, not using wxTimer?

Comment: what is the exact scenario you are trying to solve? Do you have a thread and you need to update GUI? Or there is something else? You mentioned menu and window resizing, hence I want to ask. f you want to post a message from a thread - you need to use wxThreadEvent, not wxCommandEvent.

Answer (score 0):

`wxTimer` is indeed unsuitable if you need precise timing, it works on "best effort" basis and using a worker thread is a good idea if you need something more exact. You don't say how do you post events from it, but if you use `wxQueueEvent()` or `CallAfter()` (which uses events under the hood too), it should already work.

Historically there were some bugs which resulted in posted events not being processed while a local system modal event loop is running (which is the case while resizing or a menu is open), but it *should* work, so if it doesn't, please [report it as a bug](https://www.wxwidgets.org/develop/how-to-report-issues/).

Comment: I use a wxCommandEvent that I create as a local variable in the thread function, then post it with wxPostEvent to the main frame (there is only one frame in this application).

Comment: I tried wxQueueEvent also but this does not work with a local variable but only with a dynamically created one.
How do I use CallAfter? Can you give an example please?
Somewhere I read I have to use event.Skip(); at the end of the timer event function. What is that about? I don't use it in the menu event functions.

Comment: Another detail on the behaviour: when I open a menu the processing of the timer events stops but timer events will be processed as long as I move the mouse pointer inside the application window.

Comment: You have to use a heap-allocated event when posting it between threads. Please grep for `CallAfter()` in wx own sources, you will find several examples of using it.